# Variables not equaling with SSH query in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables, powershell-remoting

having a bit of an issue.
trying to make a check if the user has OpenSSH and put that output in a variable
then compare with a variable that has 'not installed' message and then install it

```
clear

$test = Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

$notinstalled = 'Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent'

if ($test -eq $notinstalled)
{
Write-Output 'Not Installed'
}
```

But after some testing thinking it was problems with empty spaces in the pre written string I tried this and it didn't work. which I though should have worked 100% but it outputs nothing

```
$t = Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

$t1 = $t

if ($t1 -eq $t)
{
Write-Output 'Correct'
}
```

Im sorry if I have taken this in the complete wrong direction. open to any info, I have been stumpt for a while. Thank you

Output of $test, and of {Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'} is:

```
Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
```

Comment: Can you please share the result of `$test`? I'm quite sure it delivers some kind of object we can test your condition against instead of just some huge string.

Comment: $test - output is:

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compare an `object[]` with a `string`:

```
PS /> $test = Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

PS /> $test.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name             BaseType
-------- -------- ----             --------
True     True     Object[]         System.Array
```

Since your command is returning an array you would need to filter it first before comparing, for example if you wanted to check if *OpenSSH.Server* was installed, you could do:

```
$test = Get-WindowsCapability | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

$openSSHserver = $test | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -match 'OpenSSH.Server' -and $_.State -eq 'Installed'
}

# If this variable is null, meaning, no object was found where the property
# Name matches OpenSSH.Server and it's state is Installed then, display message
if(-not $openSSHserver)
{
    Write-Output 'Not Installed'
}
```

This could be even more simplified if you target the OpenSSH you're looking for:

```
filter is-SSHInstalled {
    if($_.State -ne 'Installed')
    {
        '{0} is Not Installed' -f $_.Name
    }
}

Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -Match 'OpenSSH.Server' | is-SSHInstalled
```

Which yields:

```
PS /> Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -Match 'OpenSSH.Server' | is-SSHInstalled
OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0 is Not Installed
```

---

Note, in my knowledge (I may be wrong), **all** cmdlets designed by Microsoft return `objects`. If you're going to be working with PowerShell, this is something you need to get used to and filtering objects is an essential part of this jazz. I would recommend starting from [about_Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_objects?view=powershell-7.1#:%7E:text=objects%20in%20PowerShell.-,Long%20Description,data%20that%20represents%20an%20item.) and then reading all the ***See Also*** links (methods, properties, pipelines, etc).

Comment: Can a `filter` be declared like that or is it a `function`? I wasn't able to find any documentation.

Comment: @alexzelaya yep, they are called `PowerShell Filter`. It's not well documented by Microsoft (in my knowledge), probably I would start from [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/the-powershell-filter-2/). Basically, they're a shorter version of an advanced function.

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely play around with this :) You have my upvote.

Comment: @alexzelaya basically, it's a shorter version of the `process {...}` block of an advanced function and I guess MS didn't document it because it's not a very good practice but I like them :P

Comment: Might come in handy when I need to write some very clean code where a `Where-Object` would just be very messy when piping or even using `swtich`.

Answer (score 0):

First off given your condition I'm assuming you're searching for the OpenSSH.Server.

```
$test = Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH.Server*'

if ($test.State -eq "NotPresent") {
    Write-Output 'Not Installed'
}
```

If both have to be checked:

```
$test = Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'
foreach ($r in $test) {
   if ($r.State -eq "NotPresent") {
      Write-Output "$($r.Name) is not installed"'
   }
```

Comment: @Cool_Kid, when running a cmdlet most of the time the result is an object. If there is more than one result you will have to iterate through all of them with a `foreach` statement. Just calling out the variable does not return a string. I found this really cool article for you: https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-objects/